# rewrite target not working

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to use rewrite target from kubernetes with `gcloud` but it doesn't seem to be respected. My code is the following. Maybe there's something I'm not seen:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: projectip
spec:

  rules:
  - host: mycustomdomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /api/*
        backend:
          serviceName: backend
          servicePort: 80
```

When I do `curl mycustomdomain.com/api/something` my backend is always receiving `backend/api/something` instead of `backend/something`. I'm really out of ideas and I could use some help.

Comment: Seems like google still not supporting that

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using the kubernetes ingress-nginx.

Looking at your ingress manifest, it seems like the rewrite annotation is wrong.

According to the documentation it should be:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target

Here's the link to th documentation:

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/annotations.md#rewrite

Comment: I'm using the one that comes as default ([reference here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout)). However at some point I was also using the properties `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` and `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` that were not working for me.

Comment: What happens if you remove the star at the path.  Instead of /*, use /.  I was trying /* yesterday and it wasn't working for me.

Comment: actually, just `/` without `/*` wasn't working for me. I don't know why. Before I was using kubernetes with azure and `/` was working, now with gcloud for some reason it wasn't working, i'll debug that later in the day

Comment: Just guessing here, how many ingress controller you have? Would be nice if you can provide your ingress controller manifest too.  Also looking at the sample in github, path: /api alone might do the trick. Can u omit the forward slash after "/api"?

Answer (score 1):

The term `rewrite-target` is misleading: it is about the path of the **incoming** request.

This might work: use one ingress with `rewrite-target: /` and `path: /` for the frontend only, and one ingress with `rewrite-target: /api` and `path: /` for the backend only.

Comment: But if I use 2 ingress, I'll be using 2 load balancers isn't it? At least I think that happens with [`gce ingress`](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce). As a workaround, I'm using `ingress-nginx` with the drawback that I cannot get an static ip.

Comment: No, you use the same loadbalancer = ingress controller for both Ingresses.

Comment: I'll test it tomorrow and I'll let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, from my testing `rewrite-target` is the outgoing rewritten url, it's not misleading.

Answer (score 1):

If you have used helm to install nginx ingress, you can also look at the rewrite example in the helm chart directory. It can be found at `<helm-chart-directory>/examples/rewrite`. There should be a README.md which should help.

In my case, the required annotation was `nginx.org\rewrite:"<service-name-1>:<rewrite-target-1>;<service-name-2>:<rewrite-target-2>"`